# An error occurred while updating the entries - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have this stupid error In Entity Framework.

I have a class called List which has an `ICollection` of `Users`

```
public class List
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User>Users{get;set;}
}

public class User
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<List>Lists{get;set;}
}
```

Say I create a list and add a `User` to it, it throws an error

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Upon seeing the inner exception, it says

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Upon inspecting the entities, the list (with id 1) has a user with id 1 which internally has a list with id 1 which again has this user and so on and so forth.

Upon calling the `dbContext.Save()` this exception occurs.

How is it possible to solve this issue??

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your comments. But thats not the case. You have got it completely wrong. I am not trying to create another List with Id 1. This error happens when it tries to insert into the association table. I will update my question to make it a bit more clear.